# How to get rid of substrings in specific lines using bash?

Tags: awk

I have a file which looks like this

```
>4RYF_1|Chains A, B, C, D, E, F, G|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MAENTKNENITNILTQKLIDTRTVLIYGEINQELAEDVSKQLLLLESISNDPITIFINSQGGHVEAGDTIHDMIKFIKPTVKVVGTGWVASAGITIYLAAEKENRFSLPNTRYMIHQPAGGVQGQSTEIEIEAKEIIRMRERINRLIAEATGQSYEQISKDTDRNFWLSVNEAKDYGIVNEIIENRDGLKMASWSHPQFEK
>4RYF_2|Chains H, I, J, K, L, M, N|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
```

I want to get rid of all the rest of chains and to display this instead:

```
>4RYF_1|Chain A|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MAENTKNENITNILTQKLIDTRTVLIYGEINQELAEDVSKQLLLLESISNDPITIFINSQGGHVEAGDTIHDMIKFIKPTVKVVGTGWVASAGITIYLAAEKENRFSLPNTRYMIHQPAGGVQGQSTEIEIEAKEIIRMRERINRLIAEATGQSYEQISKDTDRNFWLSVNEAKDYGIVNEIIENRDGLKMASWSHPQFEK
>4RYF_2|Chain H|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
```

Basically changing Chains by Chain and keeping only the first letter.

I tried doing something like this, but it is obviously adding pipes at the end of lines I don't want. How can I fix it?

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1"|"substr($2,1,5)substr($2,7,2)"|"$3"|"$4}'  sample

>4RYF_1|Chain A|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MAENTKNENITNILTQKLIDTRTVLIYGEINQELAEDVSKQLLLLESISNDPITIFINSQGGHVEAGDTIHDMIKFIKPTVKVVGTGWVASAGITIYLAAEKENRFSLPNTRYMIHQPAGGVQGQSTEIEIEAKEIIRMRERINRLIAEATGQSYEQISKDTDRNFWLSVNEAKDYGIVNEIIENRDGLKMASWSHPQFEK|||
>4RYF_2|Chain H|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH|||
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }                    # define input/output field delimiter

/^>/  {                                 # if line starts with ">" then ...
        split($2,arr,",")               # split field #2 based on comma delimiter; store results in array arr[]
        sub("Chains","Chain",arr[1])    # change "Chains" to "Chain" in first array entry
        $2=arr[1]                       # redefine field #2 as first array entry
      }
1                                       # print current line
' gene.dat

# or as a one-liner:

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} /^>/ {split($2,arr,",");sub("Chains","Chain",arr[1]);$2=arr[1]} 1' gene.dat
```

Both generate:

```
>4RYF_1|Chain A|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MAENTKNENITNILTQKLIDTRTVLIYGEINQELAEDVSKQLLLLESISNDPITIFINSQGGHVEAGDTIHDMIKFIKPTVKVVGTGWVASAGITIYLAAEKENRFSLPNTRYMIHQPAGGVQGQSTEIEIEAKEIIRMRERINRLIAEATGQSYEQISKDTDRNFWLSVNEAKDYGIVNEIIENRDGLKMASWSHPQFEK
>4RYF_2|Chain H|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple substitution on individual lines like this is really the job sed is best at:

```
$ sed 's/Chains\( .\)[^|]*/Chain\1/' file
>4RYF_1|Chain A|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MAENTKNENITNILTQKLIDTRTVLIYGEINQELAEDVSKQLLLLESISNDPITIFINSQGGHVEAGDTIHDMIKFIKPTVKVVGTGWVASAGITIYLAAEKENRFSLPNTRYMIHQPAGGVQGQSTEIEIEAKEIIRMRERINRLIAEATGQSYEQISKDTDRNFWLSVNEAKDYGIVNEIIENRDGLKMASWSHPQFEK
>4RYF_2|Chain H|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
```

but if you prefer to use awk then using GNU awk for `gensub()`:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/Chains( .)[^|]*/,"Chain\\1",1)}' file
>4RYF_1|Chain A|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MAENTKNENITNILTQKLIDTRTVLIYGEINQELAEDVSKQLLLLESISNDPITIFINSQGGHVEAGDTIHDMIKFIKPTVKVVGTGWVASAGITIYLAAEKENRFSLPNTRYMIHQPAGGVQGQSTEIEIEAKEIIRMRERINRLIAEATGQSYEQISKDTDRNFWLSVNEAKDYGIVNEIIENRDGLKMASWSHPQFEK
>4RYF_2|Chain H|ATP-dependent Clp protease proteolytic subunit|Listeria monocytogenes (1639)
MNLIPTVIEQTSRGERAYDIYSRLLKDRIIMLGSAIDDNVANSIVSQLLFLDAQDPEKDIFLYINSPGGSISAGMAIYDTMNFVKADVQTIGMGMAASMGSFLLTAGANGKRFALPNAEIMIHQPLGGAQGQATEIEIAARHILKIKERMNTIMAEKTGQPYEVIARDTDRDNFMTAQEAKDYGLIDDIIINKSGLKGHHHHHH
```